# Dynamic Interpreter and Prefilled Query with Apache Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a requirement where user will click on a hyperlink from front end and on clicking of it, it should take us to Zeppelin UI pre-filled with a specific query and with dynamic interpreter config ( different database = different hyperlinks). I am trying to find it in documentation, but unable to find it.

If anyone has any suggestions or pointers, that will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vatsal

Comment: Hi, you can create interpretet + note + paragraph using API. http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/usage/rest_api/interpreter.html

Comment: @1ambda - I am able to create an interpreter and can connect to my data source (Kylin). But as per interpreter settings, only one project can be configured at a time. How can I open zeppelin UI with preconfigured dynamic project specific to that request and prefilled SQL?